Data flow diagram generation
Can I get some suggestions on the best tools to use to generate data flow diagrams of the entire codebase. I would like to be able to visualise the architecture and code design in a diagram. The idea is that a design phase would analyse the flow and make adjustments towards it, then when after development we can validate the generated flow diagram matches the design phase proposed changes.
My technologies that any tools would need to be able to support:

Java or Kotlin language
Maven build tool

